# How to determine if JPEG image has been recompressed?

Tags: jpeg

So I have a bunch of photos: original, directly from the camera, and ones modified by Picasa. I *think* that Picasa only modified EXIF data, but I want to be sure. Is there any way to checksum, or software to compare, just the JPEG image data?

Preferably via Linux console.

Comment: Oh that's cool, downvote without telling why. Thanks, stranger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some that you know are not modified, you could look at the sampling in the SOF marker and the quantizations tables in the DQT markets. It is likely they will have the same values.

Check your possibly modified files and see if they have the same values.